# ASP.Net MVC + Facebook oAuth + rewrite rule cause response_type=code

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, facebook-oauth

I'm experimenting an issue when I create some rewrite rule into my ASP.Net app.

When I activate this rule :

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Main Rule" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^.*" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="^/api/" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="^/token" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

My application will try to authenticate through Facebook with response type : code instead of token.

When I disable It, I'm well redirecting with response_type = token

Is there anybody who had to deal with it ?
thank you.

Comment: may be because it intercepts the request to facebook which has a url like `https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token`

Comment: This rewrite rul is a server rewite rule.
I think (and hope this cannot intercepts the facebook request).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found the solution. 
The problem was that my rule was catching the facebook response. The owin Context was attempting to catch the code and then ask facebook to retrieve the token. Bu as my rule was done like previously, it was my App who catched the facebook code...

I had to change my rule in order to not treat signin requests like this:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Main Rule" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="^/api/" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="^/signin" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Hope this will help.
Regards,